# If route-refresh is negotiated BGP hard reset never happens?

Tags: bgp

When route-refresh capability is negotiated between two BGP peers , "clear ip bgp *" will not trigger a hard-reset at all. Is it right to say that hard reset never happens with router with route-refresh capabilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that command will trigger a hard-reset of all peerings.

Negotiating route-refresh means you can perform a soft-reset using, for example `clear ip bgp * soft` - doing so requires negotiating route-refresh OR `soft-reconfiguration inbound`

Note that soft-reconfiguration inbound is a waste of RAM and should generally be avoided if route-refresh capability is available - the only exceptions are where the time/bandwidth consumption is considered more important.

If you want to be able to trigger a hard reset without loss of forwarding, look at BGP graceful-restart